# How to highlight every occurence of a word in a TextArea?

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I try to highlight ever occurrence of a word matching a search term. But there is always only the first occurrence highlighted. Is it possible that the SelectRange() method can only highlight one word at a time? If yes, is there a different way?

```
findButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override 
    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        errorText.setText("");
        textArea.deselect();
        Matcher matcher;
        Pattern findWord;

        if (textField.getText() != null && !textField.getText().isEmpty() && upperLowerCaseMenuItem.isSelected()) {
            findWord = Pattern.compile(textField.getText());
            matcher = findWord.matcher(textArea.getText());
        while (matcher.find()) {
            textArea.selectRange(matcher.start(), matcher.end()); 
        } 
        }else {
            errorText.setText("Missing search key");
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible task with `TextArea` because this control cannot select noncontinuous text. If you take a look on the [`selectionProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#selectionProperty) of `TextArea`:

```
public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<IndexRange> selectionProperty
```

it stores only a single `IndexRange`:

> Class representing a contiguous range of integral values.

You could use [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) from [Tomas Mikula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572599/tomas-mikula) which control can be used to add style to multiple text ranges.